# Daterangepicker - singleDatePicker - Show 2 months

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using `daterangepicker`. All works fine.

Now, when `"singleDatePicker": true`, is it possible to show 2 months range?

**HTML:**

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="tripOne" name="tripOne" />
```

**JS:**

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var maxLimitDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear() + 1, nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('input[name="tripOne"]').daterangepicker({
"autoApply": true,
"autoUpdateInput": false,
"singleDatePicker": true,
"minDate": today,
"maxDate": maxLimitDate,
"opens": "left",
"locale": {
    format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
  }
}, function (start, end) {
  $("#tripOne").val(start.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
  $('#tripOne').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
});
```

Comment: it works, but if you select a date fromthe right calendar, this calendar switch to the left and next month is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show two months with singleDatePicker, add `$('.calendar.right').show();`

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbudooem/)**

To hide the right arrow, edit daterangepicker.js

Find this line,

```
if ((!maxDate || maxDate.isAfter(calendar.lastDay)) && (!this.linkedCalendars || side == 'right' || this.singleDatePicker))
```

and remove `|| this.singleDatePicker`

This will hide the right arrow on the first calendar.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to the answer of Indrajeet Patil. It is possible to hide the right arrow in the left calendar by:

```
$('.calendar.left .next.available').hide();
```